# TRABAJAR CON DATAFRAMES CONCATENADOS

Tags: python-3.x

estoy aprendiendo a trabajar con Dataframes en python, cree un dataframe concatenando otros dataframes, el asunto es que como son varios que estan dentro de uno solo cada vez que termina un dato que era de un dataframe y sigue otro dato de otro Dataframe la indexacion cambia por ejemplo

```
    X        Y

 0  dato1  datoa

 1  dato2  datob  

 2  dato3  datoc

 3  dato4  datod

 0  dato1  datoa
```

En este caso pongo como ejemplo que el indice 3 es ultimo dato de un dataframe y luego comienza otra vez desde el indice cero que correponde a otro dato de otro dataframe, el asunto es que necesito agregar otras columnas pero asigar valores dependiendo del Dataframe es decir detectar que de cero a 3 es uno y agregar unos valores luego detecta que vuelve a ser cero de ahi hasta que termine agregar otros tipos de valores y así sucesivamente hasta acabar con todos los datos

ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer

```
      X      Y     columnanueva

 0  dato1  datoa        11

 1  dato2  datob        12

 2  dato3  datoc        13

 3  dato4  datod        14

 0  dato1  datoa        j
```

En el ejemplo pongo otra columna y asigno valores cuando vuelve a cero es otro dataframe y por ende corresponde otro tipo de valores, he estado buscando informacion pero hasta ahora no se como resolver esto, les agradecería mucho su colaboración.

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente la solución más simple es tener una nueva columna en la que cada fila procedente del mismo DF original tenga e mismo valor, a modo de clave identificativa. Lo ideal es hacer esto antes de concatenar, pero podemos recuperar esa información usando el salto en el índice:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"X": ("dato1", "dato2", "dato1", "dato2", "dato3", "dato1", "dato2"),
     "Y": ("datoa", "datob", "datoa", "datob", "datoc", "datoa", "datob")},
    index=(0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1)
    )

df["orig_df"] = (df.index <= df.index.to_series().shift()).cumsum()
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>        X      Y  orig_df
> 0  dato1  datoa        0
> 1  dato2  datob        0
> 0  dato1  datoa        1
> 1  dato2  datob        1
> 2  dato3  datoc        1
> 0  dato1  datoa        2
> 1  dato2  datob        2
> ```

Ahora es trivial usar dicha columna para aplicar las operaciones en diferenciadas según el origen de cada fila. Además, puedes reindexar o desordenar las columnas y no perderás la información sobre la procedencia de cada fila.

Comment: Amigo otra pregunta, en mi caso el dataframe lo hago para extraer información de untexto, ya que a este le aplico una función, extraigo ciertas caracteristicas de el, pero generalemnte los textos son muy grandes y la función no me permite ingresar todo sino segmentado, entonces la funcion se aplica a cada segmento entonces cuando por ejemplo viene un 30 y luego sigue un cero quiere decir que el primer segmento le extrajo de 0 a 30 y el siguiente que comienza en cero es de otro segmento entonces ese tamaño del dataframe depende de cuantas caracteriticas por segmento me extraiga

Comment: Hola David, entiendo ¿cuál es exactamente la duda?

Comment: lista5 = pd.concat([lista5,lista7],axis=0,sort=False). Lista 5 es un DataFrame que creo con las mismas columnas que tiene lista 7, en lista 7 está guardado todos los datframes separados entonces con lista 5 los pongo todos en uno y para saber cual dato es de cual, se reinicia a cero el indice, entonces con una nueva columna, quiero a todos los datos de un datframe ponerles el mismo valor, por ejemplo el primero de inicio a fin le pongo cero, el segundo de cero a fin le pongo otro valor, el tercero de cero a fin otro valor eso es lo que quiero hacer y no he logrado pensar una forma de hacerlo

Comment: Pero lista7 que es porque una lista no puede ser ¿otro dataframe?¿Una serie?

Comment: si es un dataframe perdon no lo especifique, lista 7 es otro DataFrame

Comment: Vale , si los dataframes originales no tiene todos el mismo tamaño es imposible determinar que fragmentos son de uno y cuales de otro, esa información la pierdes en el momento que juntas fragmentos de un dataframe con fragmentos de otros. Esto como comentaba en mi respuesta debes hacerlo antes, cuando tu función retorna cada fragmento, debería agregar una columna que identifique el documento original. Es simple hacerlo, pero sin saber como funciona tu función y como la llamas es complicado dar una respuesta adecuada a tu caso. Intenta proveer un [mcve] desde el principio si es posible.